# Tesseract theme menu

Tags: css, drop-down-menu, web, tesseract

I'm new to this forum so hello to all.

I'm working on a WordPress website theme called tesseract. I am new to WordPress so have limited experience working with it.

The problem I'm experience is with the menu at the top of the page. If you visit [www.avoinvents.co.uk](http://www.avoinvents.co.uk) and take a look you'll see that the categories don't sit on the same line. If I remove one of the categories the page looks much nicer and neater. All categories are necessary so I could not delete any.

Could anyone on here suggest how I make the necessary changes to fix the menu.

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here's the CSS that I changed in my browser to make the menu appear in all one line:

```
#masthead {
padding-top: 10px;
padding-bottom: 10px;
}

#site-banner-left {
width: 100%;
}
```

The main problem was that the site-banner-left CSS definition had a width of 60%, causing the text to wrap around its border, so I changed its width to 100% and added the padding to make the navigation area a little bigger. If this messes with other parts of the theme, try making the text size of the site-banner-left definition smaller instead of changing its width. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I made the change to the site-banner.css located in the CSS file within the theme. This didn’t seem to make any difference when I saved the changes. Could you make any suggestions as to what I’m doing wrong pls?

Answer (score 0):

You have limited the available width because an ancestor element, `#site-banner-left`, has a width of 60%. Increase this value or remove this rule to allow the entire menu to fit naturally.

Additionally, since the menu items are `inline-block` elements, you can force them to be on one line by setting the parent element's `white-space` to `nowrap`:

```
.nav-menu {
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply.  I think removing the rule altogether would be the best option. Could you please tell me how I do this? I have a child WordPress theme. I cannot find any reference to #site-banner-left style.css. If I open the site-banner.css located in the main theme css folder, I can find reference to this rule. If I delete the rule or change to 100% it makes no difference when I upload it. 
Can you make any suggestion as to what maybe happening?

Comment: The rule that affects `#site-banner-left` is on line 74 of your HTML, in an inline `<style>` with id `tesseract-site-banner-inline-css`. Check to make sure that this isn't the result of a theme option.

If all else fails, you can simply add a rule to your child theme's style.css that overrides the 60% width.

Comment: Hi Again. I made some changes to the functions PHP file which seems to have fixed the issue. I wasn’t able to find any reference on line 74 of the html when making the changes. Could you have a quick look and let me know if it looks of to you please?

Many thanks.

Comment: Everything looks fine now. Just to make things clear, I was referring to line 74 of the final outputted HTML, not in your template files.